# error creating migration in laravel: 'failed to open stream'

Tags: laravel-5, migration

I created my first migration `create_users_migration` using the command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

I later on realized there was an error and so deleted the migration file and decided to create different migration file with the same command above. But it keeps throwing this exception:

> [ErrorException]
>     include(/home/awa/Desktop/intern/train2/vendor/composer/../../database/migr
>     ations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php): failed to open stream: No
>      such file or directory

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did someone find what caouse this issue?

Comment: In my case, the migrations folder was missing under /project-name/database or wherever your database folder is. Just creating a new folder called 'migrations' solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I get this error on regular basis, here are some things that might help:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

or delete the cache manually in the bootstrap directory (it is responsible for the route and services cache.

also these methods could help:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
composer update
```

Composer dump-autoload regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php).

the **-o / --optimize** option converts PSR-4/PSR-0 rules into classmap rules, as a result autoloader doesn't need to access the filesystem, making it run faster - which also is often the source of the problem since Laravel autoloader uses this optimization (caching).

also rolling back the migration has helped to solve the problem several times (if the migration was successful):

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Comment: I only needed to do: composer dump-autoload

Comment: `composer dump-autoload -o` was all I needed to run. Thanks.

Comment: This helped immensely after looking for a while. But why would they decide to insert migrations into the composer `autoload_classmap`? This doesn't make very much sense to me since they're pretty much one-off files that shouldn't be loaded with usual requests.

Comment: this is super dumb but its the only solution

Comment: Just hit URL **www.yourdomain.com/clear-cache** if you created route for it.[Check my answer ] ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893051/5803974)

Answer (score 17):

i got this error and i have found a solutions over the community :

> **php artisan cache:clear**

this will delete cached files

> **composer dump-autoload**

composer dump-autoload, will re-generating optimized autoload files for your project agian

> **php artisan migrate:refresh**

then create a new fresh migrate for your database

> **php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users**

finally let's start make your new migration file

Answer (score 9):

You might then need to run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error, tried above solutions - did not work for me.
Finally I re-created the deleted migration file using following command.

```
php artisan make:migration create_my_table
```

And then I ran following command - now it is working

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Answer (score 1):

So simple and it works better. Just use:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

then make your new migration file

Answer (score 1):

Sometime it may be ***cache*** issue in **Laravel**.

No need to install composer and other things.First try simple way:-

Simply add this code in your **routes/web.php** file

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return "Cache is cleared";
});
```

In your browser just hit url

```
www.yourdomain.com/clear-cache
```

If it success it will show message

```
Cache is cleared
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that migrations folder exists inside database folder

Answer (score 0):

I have updated Laravel to a newer version, and that was the problem. I updated composer and it worked fine. In the project directory run this command:

> $ composer update

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is - whether you have a *folder* created /database/migrations
If it doesn't exist, you will get the described error :( Just create it manually and re-run command.